# Installing handlersocket

Tags: installation, rpm

I am trying to install handlersocket plugin as explained here...

http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/performance/handlersocket.html#enabling-the-plugin

I have downloaded and installed percona server and followed the steps mentioned on the above page.
But when I execute "show processlist" command it does not show handlersocket connection. Is there any other package that needs to be installed?